# dpkg-deb: error: 'mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb' is not a Debian format archive

Tags: mysql, debian

I run following command to install mysql server

```
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb
```

and get this error:

```
strong textdpkg-deb: error: 'mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb (--install):
dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing: mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be sure that downloaded file is mysql with true format.
My client does not have permission to access Mysql website from oracle in my country.
When i download mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb with

```
 wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb
```

a HTML page Error downloaded... .
You should use a proxy or VPN for downloading. I downloaded mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb with Tor browser and uploaded it on server.

Comment: You saved me much of time. F all politicians and their dictates!